# Transform data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, pivot-table

I have two problems with my data in Excel.

1. I have this table, so for every day in the year I have got 24 values, that´s 365 columns.

[image1 http://imageshack.us/a/img600/1773/dataxz.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img600/1773/dataxz.jpg)

I need to write a macro, that transform the data **vertically, below each other**. Like in the other table. So the 1.1.1996 is in (B4:B28), 2.1.1996 (B29:B53) etc. I made a simple macro but I don´t know how to continue with it automatically.

2. Second problem is the pivot table, or, how to easy make for example daily/weekly/monthly averages or sums of every columns separately. And than the graph. I made one table but it makes me wrong average

[image2 http://imageshack.us/a/img690/5305/pivottable.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img690/5305/pivottable.png)

Comment: You're dealing with two concepts here: a looping macro, and chart/graphing techniques.  Split this into two questions, and show your macro so far for the first question, and your table/graph so far for the second.

Comment: Range("AB4:AB27").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B28").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B4:B27").Select

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question wasn't clear even when the image links worked (see comment on answer).  The links are now broken and the OP hasn't returned in 3 yrs, so the question isn't answerable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question wasn't clear even when the image links worked (see comment on answer). The links are now broken and the OP hasn't returned in 3 yrs, so the question isn't answerable

Answer (score 0):

You can do the transposing without any macro:

The direct way for your first step would be to use the `TRANSPOSE` function, i.e. select a range that is 365rowsx24cols and enter `=TRANSPOSE(B4:NB27)` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, I'd recommend to address problem 1 and 2 in a slightly different manner: Translate your data to a list, i.e. a table with 365x24 rows x 3 columns: *Date*, *Hour*, *Value*. This table can then be easily be used as the source for a pivot table!

To do so, you could either use two helper columns - the first one starting at 1 and increasing every row by one until it's 24 then reset (In A2: `1`, in A3: `=IF(A2=24,1,A2+1)`), the second starting with 1 and increasing by 1 every 24 rows (B2: `1`, B3: `=IF(A3=1,B2+1,B2)`. Alternatively, you could simply use the `ROW()` function (which returns you the row of the cell with the formula if no parameter is provided) to derive the number 1 to 24 with `MOD(ROW(),24)-1` and the 1 to 365 with `INT((ROW()-2)/24)+1`. (The `+1` and `-2` is to adjust for the data table starting in row 2).

Using the `INDEX` function with those two parameters, you can now easily retrieve the data for the 3 columns:

Date: `=INDEX($B$3:$NB$3,B2)` (or without the helper columns: `=INDEX($B$3:$NB$3,INT((ROW()-2)/24)+1)`)

Hour: `=INDEX($A$4:$A$27,A2)`(or `=INDEX($A$4:$A$27,MOD(ROW(),24)-1)`)

Value: `=INDEX($B$4:$NB$27,A2,B2)`(or `=INDEX($B$4:$NB$27,MOD(ROW(),24)-1),INT((ROW()-2)/24)+1)`)

Comment: thanks, but I made a mistake. I need to put the hourly values for the days in one column. So I have column A with date and hours, or A for dates, B for hours and C for values. Some macro like this but without certain number and loop until last column   Range("AB4:AB27").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AA28").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("AC4:AC27").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AA52").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste